page of flashcards do display
I am trying to code in django pymongo with a connection to mongodb compass a flashcard app that will display the cards on from the server. I teste the mongodb server and it worked ok the problem seems to be the html or code. When I connect to the server nothing happens I will list my code in this post.
I wanted the cards to be displayed in a html web page I have changed the code and views but nothing displays.
from django.views.generic import ListView
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Card, myapp_collection
from django.http import HttpResponse
views.py file
# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("<h1>App is running</h1>")



class CardListView(ListView):
    model = Card
    queryset = Card.objects.all().order_by("box", "-date_created")[:5]
    template_name = "card_list.html"

    


def card_list(request):
    cards = Card.objects.all()  # Retrieve all cards from MongoDB
    return render(request, 'card_list.html', {'cards': cards})



#
# def get_all_myapp(request):
 #   myapp = myapp_collection.find()
 #   return myapp

#class CardListView(ListView):
#    model = Card
 ##   queryset = Card.objects.all().order_by("box", "-date_created")
  #  template_name = "card_list.html"

html file
<!-- cards/templates/cards/card_list.html -->

{% extends "myapp/base.html" %}

<h1>Card List</h1>
<ul>
{% for card in object_list %}
    <li>{{ card.your_field_name }}</li>  <!-- Make sure 'your_field_name' is a valid field of the Card model -->
{% endfor %}
</ul>

models.py


# Import necessary modules
from django.db import models
from . import db_con

# Access the 'myapp' collection from the database using db_con
myapp_collection = db_con.db['myapp']



class Card(models.Model):
    BOX_CHOICES = (
        ('A', 'Box A'),
        ('B', 'Box B'),
        ('C', 'Box C'),
    )

    # Fields for the Card model
    front_text = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    back_text = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    box = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=BOX_CHOICES)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Card ({self.id}) in {self.get_box_display()}"


Your template needs a small change. Your are sending cards to the template, not object_list.
{% extends "myapp/base.html" %}

<h1>Card List</h1>
<ul>
{% for card in cards %}  <!-- changed object_list to cards -->
    <li>{{ card.your_field_name }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>

